# Bootstrap Help (links and subpages)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

So, I have set up a few LAMP sites with bootstrap. With the original downloaded framework I have 0 problems. HOWEVER, because of my lack of skills, i build all subpages with the following mechanism (copy .index, re-name, re-edit, upload as subpage that is linked to original .index file).

NOW, the subpages work fine, however anytime I place a link on these subpages the links don't work. When I use the same link code on the original .index, the links work fine.

How can I get links on these subpages I have created?! - Thanks in advance to anyone with insight. I have been plagued by this puzzle for over 9 months (don't laugh).

- Joshua (designer/html/css level = beginner)

Comment: Simple answer, but I have _questions:_ 1. are the sub-pages in sub-directories (ie: not in the same folder as index)? 2. The links: where are they pointing to? Other subpages, or back to the index?

Comment: Kevin ard - thanks for responding!

1. no, re-named .index copies (the subpages) are in the same folder as the original .index

2. Forgot to mention this. The internal links on the subpages (back to .index) work fine. It is only the external links that are busted.

Comment: External links (to other sites) should not be changed unless you're completely changing the link target. EG: if you're linking to this page, the link should be `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681715/bootstrap-help-links-and-subpages/32681866">Your Post</a>`, whatever page it's on.

Does that do anything for you? If not, I may not be visualizing it properly. Posting your trouble code would be priceless for that.

Comment: kevin ard, thanks - however, this is the same link code that doesn't work on the subpages. Here, I copied your link code (altered slightly) and added it to one of my subpages. Here, you can see the link is busted. http://www.tutoringlosangeles.com/hangul.html (at the very top of page, links do get colored tho...)

Comment: **PRICELESS!** it's not a link issue at all! :) It's your css. In the style for `.banner-container:before` on line 469 of styles.css, that style has `bottom:0px`, which makes it consume the entire viewport, blocking mouse action. You must address that issue. when I went in with Chrome developer tools and turned off `bottom:0px;`, links all work perfectly

Comment: Kevin ard Thanks so much! - so by turned off, do you mean i only need to delete/remove "bottom:0px;".

Comment: No, please see the answer I added below. Turning off the css in that class will kill your home page banner. The appropriate fix is in the fiddle I linked. You have your page content wrapped in a banner class, which is not what you want here. Remove the entire div.banner-container, and your page works perfectly. (I tested this in-place on the page you linked to)

Answer (score 0):

You have a css error in the page, most likely due to pruning out the original home page banner. You have your page content wrapped the same way as the home page banner, which is filling the page with a blocking div. Removing that wrapper fixes the issue.

#### fix

This should be the complete content of `section#home`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardkevin84/rjq7swz1/)

In the fiddle, please note that `div.banner-container` is no longer there.

Comment: Kevin Ard you are my code savior! - please answer this final question for me tho. so with the info you gave me i seemed to have my problem solved. please check my mechanism (copied <section id="home">
  <section id="work" class="page-section page">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="heading"> found similarly coded area on subpage (<section id and <div class) copied over the code with the code you provided, and now the links work!) Please let me know if I did it wrong or if what I did will cause problems elsewhere on the page. Thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: I looked back at the linked page and what you have certainly works. However, it's not very semantic, which is important these days. [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardkevin84/6rzchbvy/) Illustrates my semantic recommendation.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to illustrate bootstrap's grid system, if you're interested. Resize the fiddle panes to see how grids kick in at different sizes to make your page _actually_ responsive.

Comment: Kevin Ard, thanks so much for all your help. Because of you I finally got to build this page http://www.losangelesteacher.com/moreHangul.html as well as put up youtube videos on one of my other pages http://www.losangelesteacher.com/chesstheory.html . Cheers!